# How can I add dynamically a textBox value using ItextSharp?

Tags: c#, textbox, itext

Hi I'm using a ITextSharp to create a PDF. This is my code:

```
private void FillForm()
{
    _path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + "\\PDF";
    string formFile = _path + "\\Test.pdf";
    string newFile = _path + "\\Test2.pdf";

    var reader = new PdfReader(formFile);
    using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create)))
    {
        AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

        var conn = new SqlConnection(DataManager.ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        var command = new SqlCommand("SQLCommand"), conn);
        var dt = new DataTable();
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

        adapter.Fill(dt);
        int rowIndex = 1;
        for (int i=0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var name = (string)dt.Rows[i]["Parameter"];
            fields.SetField("txt_" + rowIndex, name);
            rowIndex++;
        }

        stamper.FormFlattening = false;
        stamper.Close();
    }
}
```

I have a problem when I'm trying to fill the userName into textboxes. I have a list of names that I get it from the SQL query and I want to display it in different textboxes.
Only the first textBox display its value. For the others I must click on textBox to view the value inside.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Where/How do you add them to the textboxes? I can't see what relevance the code snippet has here

Comment: Here Im setting the textBox value:

 fields.SetField("user_" + rowIndex, name);

Comment: What are you using to view the file afterwards, have you tried different pdf readers?

Comment: I'm using and I have to use Adobe Reader,I haven't tried other one

Comment: I've tried with Foxit Reader now, but the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

One line is missing in your code:

```
fields.GenerateAppearances = true;
```

You need to add this line right after:

```
AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
```

Why is this happening? Your template is somewhat wrong (maybe it was created using OpenOffice): it says that the software used to fill out the form shouldn't generate the appearances of the fields. As a result the *value* of the field is added (this is proven by the fact that the text appears when you click it), but the *appearance* is missing (hence the blank fields).

Comment: I added your code, but nothing has changed, the appearance is missing again :(

Comment: Please share your PDF.

Comment: I share it in question description

Comment: I see a screen shot. Where can I download the PDF for inspection?

Comment: I can't give you a original PDF file becouse it contains a confidential information on the other pages.I'm not doing it for myself,its a client requirement. The PDF its a "ready" template that I must field it with the values from database :( sorry about that

Comment: btw does ITextSharp version matter for using yor code? I'm with 5.5.1?

Comment: The iTextSharp version doesn't matter, but we really need to look inside the PDF to find out if the `/NeedAppearances` flag is set. It there's already a `/DA` value. And so on. For instance: a known defect in Apple's Preview causes PDFs to have default appearances that consist of blank rectangles. If you don't want to share the PDF, experts can only guess (time is precious and if you expect us to guess, you're abusing our willingness to spend time without any form of compensation for our work).

Comment: @DID Without the PDF we can only guess. Thus, if you cannot share the PDF publicly, you most liekly will have to find out yourself or buy support from people ready to sign some NDA.